Why is my code jumping directly to the if (price == 0) statement and not first taking my input?
Why is my program skipping directly to the if(price == 0) case and not requesting input first?
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
#include <map>
#include <fstream>

void writeFile(string name, string surname, double final)
{
    string finalBill = std::to_string(final);

    std::ofstream MyFile(name + "order.txt");
    enter code here
    if (!MyFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: File could not be opened";
        return;
    }

    MyFile << "Name: " + name + "\nSurname: " + surname + "\nFinal bill: " + finalBill + "\n";

    MyFile.close();

    std::cout << "The bill has been written to CafeteriaBill.txt.";

}

void displayMenu()
{
    std::cout << "Items Available: \n1. Handy Andy - R15.00 \n2. Apples - R30.00 \n3. Chocolate - R25.00  \n4. Juice boxes - R10.00 \n5. Broom - R20.00 \n6. Wine - R35.00 \n7. Sugar - R18.00 \n8. Eggs - R40.00 \n9. Rice - R55.00 \n10. Bread - R 15.00 ";
}

int getPrice(string SelectedItem)
{
    if (SelectedItem == "Handy Andy")
    {
        return 30;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Apples")
    {
        return 25;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Chocolate")
    {
        return 20;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Juice boxes")
    {
        return 45;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Broom")
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Wine")
    {
        return 70;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Sugar")
    {
        return 35;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Eggs")
    {
        return 40;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Rice")
    {
        return 55;
    }
    else if (SelectedItem == "Bread")
    {
        return 15;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int inputAmount;
    string inputSelection;
    string custID;
    char anotherBool;
    double price;
    double fullPrice;
    double totalPrice = 0;
    double discountPrice;

    std::cout << "Please enter your customer ID: ";
    std::cin >> custID;

    displayMenu();

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Select an item: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, inputSelection);

        price = getPrice(inputSelection);

        if (price == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid item selected, please enter another item";
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Select item amount of item " << i << ":";
        std::cin >> inputAmount;

        fullPrice = price * inputAmount;

        totalPrice += fullPrice;
        

        std::cout << "Would you like to select another item (y/n) ? ";
        std::cin >> anotherBool;

        if (anotherBool == 'n')
        {
                break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    std::cout << "Total Bill R: " << totalPrice << "\n";

    discountPrice = totalPrice - (totalPrice / 100 * 5);

    if (totalPrice > 200)
    {
        std::cout << "Discount applied. \n";
        std::cout << "Final Bill: R" << discountPrice << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No discount applied. \n";
        std::cout << "Final Bill: R" << totalPrice << "\n";
    }

    //writeFile(discountPrice);
}

You can ignore the rest of the code, unless it impacts this in some way. The writing to file function is not being called at all, just included to make sure you have all the details in case there is something I don't understand.

std::cin >> custID leaves a newline in the input buffer, std::getline then returns just this newline (an empty string)

It's good that you provided a complete program, and it's good that you are aware enough to know that there are things you will not understand. However you could have posted a much smaller program by removing the parts that you thought were probably irrelevant and then checking if the issue you are asking about still persists. This is what we call a [mre] and it's how you should post code here. Having said all that, the linked duplicate is the answer to your question.
